# Django messages, count number of messages between two users

Tags: django, django-models

Im using django-postman as user to user messaging system. now i want to show in the template how many messages were sent between 2 users

in models.py

```
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',
    null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("sender"))
        recipient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',
    null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("recipient"))
```

how can i count how many messages were written between two users?

Answer (score 0):

first Filter the their both message with a query with the .filter(), then count the total number of items in the querysets with .len() or .count()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model is called Message you can do like:

```
# Returns the number of messages exchanged between SENDER_USER AND RECEIVER_USER
exchanged_messages = Message.objects.filter(sender=SENDER_USER).filter(receiver=RECEIVER_USER).count()
```

Comment: This will only count messages from `SENDER_USER` to `RECEIVER_USER` to get  the correct **number of messages between two users**  you need to count also the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model for messages it's called `Message`. We want to know how many messages there are between `user_1` and `user_2`, that means in how many messages we have `user_1` as sender, `user_2` as the receiver and vice-versa.

I would use a [Q expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to express such condition:

```
condition = (
    Q(sender=user_1, receiver=user_2) | Q(sender=user_2, receiver=user_1) 
)


Message.objects.filter(condition).count()
```

Comment: ok, I have a little bit more. But I have my problems with the Django Queries. is there such a thing as a query to Django translator? 

`Message.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM messager_message WHERE recipient_id = '" + str(self.request.user.id) + "' OR sender_id = '" + str(self.request.user.id) + "'")`
        `